# how can I pass the variables to my vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, components

I am working on a vuejs repeatable component that will allow a user to due several things---enter a question and select the answer type from the drop down. Issue is based on the type, I need to display a select number of boxes if its multiple choices so it can update an array. I cannot figure out how or where to add this. I also need to make these variable (f1 and f2 dynamic) so that it can be reused at other times. So if its a single line choose f1 if it is multiple choice select f2. Someone please provide some direction

```js
Vue.component('my-input', {
  template: '<input v-attr="name: name" v-model="value" type="text">' + '<select>' + '<option value="type1">Multiple Choice</option>' + '<option value="type2">single line</option>' + '<option value="type3">multi-line</option>' + '</select><br>'+'<br>'+'</br>',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      brand: 'multiple-choice',
      options: ['option a, option b'] };

  },
  props: ['name'] });


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      message:'',
    inputs: [{ type: 'my-input' }]
 },
 mounted: function () {
    this.getAllPages();
},
   methods: {
    addInput() {
      this.inputs.push({ type: 'my-input' });
    },
    getAllPages: function () {
        var vm = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: vm.config.domainRoot + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + vm.config.listName + "')/items",
            type: 'Get',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                vm.pages = data.d.results;
                console.log(vm.pages);
            }

        })
    },
    createCustomL:function(){
   


        // Get filed collection
        var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

        var f1 = clientContext.castTo(
        fldCollection.addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="NewField" Name="NewField" Required="True"/>', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType),
        SP.FieldText);
        f1.set_title("q1");
        f1.set_description(mydescription);
        f1.update();


        //Get filed collection
        var fldCollection = oList.get_fields();

     
        var f2 = clientContext.castTo(
            oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field Type="Choice" DisplayName="state" Name="fldchoice" />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.addToDefaultContentType),
            SP.FieldChoice);
var choices = Array("None", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Georgia", "Indiana");
f2.set_choices(choices);
f2.update();







}


   }




});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vue.js repeater</title>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div id="app">




<p>Enter your ques</p>


  <component v-repeat="inputs" is="{{ type }}" name="inputs[]">

  </component>
  <button v-on="click: addInput">Add Question</button>
 
</div>
<br>
<button v-on:click="createCustom">Generate</button>
<!-- partial -->

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/0.12.8/vue.js'></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand correctly but if you want to pass different data to your component dynamically you can use props.
Take a look here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html